# Certain object properties undefined in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a container component which fetches weather data from https://openweathermap.org/. The container component then feeds that state data into a presentational component.

While some of the state properties exist, in the presentational component, others however are undefined. If I wrap them in a timeout however they appear.

I've been searching for why this might be but I've been unable to find any reasons why they'd be undefined after being fetched in the container component and passed into the presentational component.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/ZCKVNS/pen/wpGaMe?editors=0010

Article about presentational and container components: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

```
const App = data => {

  setTimeout( () => {
    console.log('clouds', data.data.clouds.all); //defined
    console.log('lat',data.data.coord.lat); //defined
    console.log('lon', data.data.coord.lon); //defined
  }, 100);

  return (
    <div>
        { data.data.clouds.all } <!-- Not defined -->
    </div>
  );
}

class AppContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { data: {} };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch( 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=43055,us&appid=4e08bb16c8936bd92b4780f9e2cdf00f' )
        .then( res => res.json() )
        .then( data => this.setState( { data } ) );
  }

  render() {
    return React.createElement( App, { data: this.state.data } );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <AppContainer />,
  document.getElementById( 'container' )
);
```

Comment: That's because the fetch hasn't completed when you first render the component.

Comment: Ok, so I presume I could delay the render until the fetch has been completed? Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just return `null` from `App` until you receive the data, or, as a convention, return some kind of UI (such as a loading icon) while the fetch is completing:

In `AppContainer`:

```
this.state = { data: null }; // so ternary operator is falsey when data isn't done fetching
```

Then in `App`:

```
return (
  <div>
    { 
      data.data ?
        data.data.clouds.all
      :
        <img src={LOADING_ICON_HERE} />
    }
  </div>
);
```

What this does is check if the prop `data` exists. If it does then it renders `data.data.clouds.all`. If not, it shows a loading icon while the request finishes. If you didn't want to show anything you could shorten it to:

```
{ 
  data.data &&
    data.data.clouds.all
}
```